# How to get the last word position in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As the title suggests how can i get the position of text in textarea. Lets take an example:- 
I have a textarea with the value JAVASCRIPT IS A CLIENT SIDE PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE.

```
<textarea>JAVASCRIPT IS A CLIENT SIDE PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE</textarea>
```

My Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/83ogr3t8/

Is there any way through which i can get the position of last word that i typed in textarea . I don't want to use any plugin for this , it would be better if thing can be done with JavaScript only. Please help me i am really stuck finding the answer for this question. 
**I meant that i want to get top and left position of the text**

Comment: What do you mean the position? X.Y. Coord?

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon  Yes if you meant top and left position

Comment: Good point @Karl, I was writing an answer to find the text index - Hudixt you need to make your question clearer

Comment: @freefaller and Karl-André Gagnon Can you answer my question. I am really stuck here finding answer for this for 3 hours

Comment: Please define position unit. Rows and columns? Characters from the beginning of the textarea? Pixels related to the top-left corner of the textarea? Something else?

Comment: I have found some libraries. Do you want them?

Comment: *Can you answer my question* Nope - if it was the text index (i.e. the number of character) then fine, but I wouldn't have a clue how to get physical position of the last word

Comment: If you use a monospaced font it would be possible by counting the characters before the last word and multiplying by the width of each character.

Comment: @Teemu Because i am not understanding them. Can you please tell what necessary information should i give more

Comment: @Hudixt I don't have the answer worked out. If you look up what a monospaced font is, you should be able to work it out from there. If you run into issues, ask a question on that. There's no quick and simple solution that I'm aware of.

Comment: @Hudixt - Do you need the position of the last word relative the the textarea or relative to the entire page?

Comment: @BSMP Relative to the entire page

Comment: @Hudixt That's the information we needed. Makes the task really difficult too, especially in the case "last word that i typed". You could have typed it anywhere on the textarea. Now one more question: When and where you will need this information? In an event handler? Real-time? Something else?

Comment: @Teemu event handler

Comment: @Hudixt, since the cursor has to be at the end of the last word they typed (at least until they click or tab somewhere else), would keeping track of the cursor position until they stop typing work? The code Dhruv Ramani found might work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a few libraries that might help you :

- [Text Area Helper](https://github.com/Codecademy/textarea-helper)
- [Text Caret Position](https://github.com/component/textarea-caret-position)

Hope these help. I think the only option you have now are these.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/83ogr3t8/1/

```
function getLastPosition(){
   var str = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
   var strLeng = str.substr().length-1;
   console.log(strLeng);
}

getLastPosition();
```

Comment: "__i want to get top and left position of the text__" This snippet gives only one value.

Comment: Ahh this gives the character position. I'm not sure how you would get X,Y coordinates. What is the bigger goal? What are you going to do with the X, Y

Comment: That's what people have been asking in the comments ; ).